# Caurina Tweener Transition & Video Stream Time (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming

We are streaming an .flv file and using the stream time to trigger animations that utilize Caurina transitions. For whatever reaseon a few parameters aren't working at all or not fully; for example the delay function and a few transitions are ignored.
So my question is, can the stream time be used as a trigger or is the stream time causing conflicts?
An example of what we are doing is below:

```
conn= new NetConnection();
conn.connect(null);
stream=new NetStream(conn);

framesCurrent=(stream.time)*1000;

if (framesCurrent>=15400) 
{ 
    Tweener.addTween(bullet01, {alpha:1, time:.35, transition:"easeInOutSine"}); 
    Tweener.addTween(text01, {alpha:1, time:.35, transition:"easeInOutSine"}); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how Tweener shouldn't work correctly when called like this, but:

1. Do you actually loop on Event.ENTER_FRAME or do you have a timer to call everything below `framesCurrent=stream.time*1000;`?  If your code is exactly what you posted above, then it's no surprise the tweens aren't executed - the if-statement is called at the time you start your NetStream, so it will never be at 15.4 seconds play time.
2. Instead of using such a loop, have you considered using event cue points in your FLV to trigger the tweens?  You can put a switch statement inside [stream.onCuePoint](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonCuePoint) and have your tweens execute on named events, which will be triggered at exactly the right point in time.  Check out this [video tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/cs4/articles/lrvid4111_xp.html) on how to set and react to event cue points (Note:The tutorial uses AfterEffects markers, but you can easily set and/or add events to a FLV in Adobe Media Encoder.  Everything that they show in Flash, you can use to see how it's done.)